# Check all conditions before processing

Tags: c#, code-coverage, crm, rules

**Background:**

I'm building a system to assign academic advisors to university students based on the student's attributes and advisor's acceptance. Now I want to check to see if every possible student can be assigned an advisor before I start processing students and committing changes to our CRM and Active Directory. There are about 15,000 records, so I don't want to commit changes unless all students have an advisor.

My current system has an 'AdvisorGroup' object to hold a list of 'AdvisorRules.' My 'AdvisorRules' object is populated from CRM:

```
class AdvisorRule
{
    public AdvisorCondition Condition { get; set; }
    public AdvisorField Field { get; set; }
    public String Value { get; set; }
}
```

`AdvisorCondition` can be LessThanEqual, GreaterThanEqual, or Equal. `AdivsorField` can be  Credit(how many credits each advisor will accept), international(if the advisor accepts intentional students), honors(if the advisor accepts honors students or not) and lastName(last names the advisor will accept.)

'Value' is the target that is compared to 'AdvisorField.' For example the list of AdvisorRules in an AdvisorGroup could hold the following rules:

1. AdvisorCondition = "Equal" AdvisorField = "International" Value = No
2. AdvisorCondition = "Equal" AdvisorField = "honors" Value = No
3. AdvisorCondition = "LessThanEqual" AdvisorField = "Credit" Value = 89
4. AdvisorCondition = "Equal" AdvisorField = "LastName" Value = A
5. AdvisorCondition = "Equal" AdvisorField = "LastName" Value = B

This advisor would accept a student with a last name starting with A or B, with less than 89 credits, and is not an international or honors student.

---

**Question:**

Is there a way to check to make sure every possible student will be assigned an advisor before I start processing? I'm trying not to be extremely explicit in my coding. I was thinking something like this, but would be open to redesigning if I can find a better way:

```
    private bool checkRuleCoverage()
    {
        //somehow generate list of possible scenarios here
        foreach (possible scenario in list of possible scenarios)
        {
            bool covered = isCovered(possible scenario);
            if(!covered) {throw error  and return}
        }
    }

    private bool isCovered(List<AdvisorGroup> adGroups, possibleScenario ps)
    {
        foreach (AdvisorGroup advisor in adGroups)
        {
            foreach (AdvisorRule rule in advisor.rules)
            {
                if(advisor.rules == ps)
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: no body will read your entrie post. Be precise to get a precise answer.

Comment: tl;dr; Side notes: please avoid "thank you notes", feel free to discuss on [meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). Also Please explain what problem you have with `foreach` and why you expect it to not iterate over each item in a sequence.

Comment: I edited the question, my problem is not iterating through all the rules in all the adviser groups, its finding a way to make sure there are no gaps in the rules and that every student will be assigned an adviser before I start processing.

Comment: Is there a limit to the number of students that can be assigned a certain advisor? If not, you just need to check that there is no student that can't be assigned to any of the possible advisors.

Answer (score 0):

If you have all of your student records in a database, then the solution would be to use set logic with appropriate indexing to get the answer. For example, you could code your own solution such that you sort the student body along each of the possible values that an advisor rule applies to.

Then, without iterating (though you've already iterated in order to sort) you can find all of the students below x or over y on a certain train, and then compare that to the students outside of the range on another stat and so on. Any student outside of the range on all stats like Mao47's comment suggest would be un-advisable.

Of course, in the time it took you to code this in C# you could have just iterated over the advisor rules and found the values of the ranges and applied this to a where clause in a select on SQLServer or MySQL or any DB that's set-based.

Of course, this rough check misses out on the possibility of partial rule-sets, where a student is outside of the range of all but 1 advisor rule, and then that 1 rule is not enough because the advisors also have other requirements. In order to solve that, you will have to have multiple advisor-rule-set-ranges, or rather, you will iterate over all advisor-rules in the worst case. Doing this in the DB will probably still be ok, as long as the student's scores on the rules-properties are properly indexed.